# swagger api rabbitmq response queue object

Tags: typescript, promise, rabbitmq, swagger

I'm using [tsoa](https://github.com/lukeautry/tsoa) for generate swagger definition and trying to send api request to rabbitmq i'm using [facundoolano](https://facundoolano.wordpress.com/2016/06/26/real-world-rpc-with-rabbitmq-and-node-js/) implementation to connect rabbitmq

```
import { configuration, random, uuid, amqp } from '../config';
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const REPLY_QUEUE = 'amq.rabbitmq.reply-to';
const createClient = () => amqp.connect(configuration.amqpUrl)
    .then((conn) => conn.createChannel())
    .then((channel: any) => {
        // create an event emitter where rpc responses will be published by correlationId
        channel.responseEmitter = new EventEmitter();
        channel.responseEmitter.setMaxListeners(0);
        channel.consume(REPLY_QUEUE,
            (msg: any) => channel.responseEmitter.emit(msg.properties.correlationId, msg.content),
            { noAck: true });
        return channel;
    });

const sendRPCMessage = (channel: any, message: any, rpcQueue: any) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const correlationId = uuid.v4();
    // listen for the content emitted on the correlationId event
    try {
        channel.responseEmitter.once(correlationId, resolve);
        channel.sendToQueue(rpcQueue, new Buffer(JSON.stringify(message)), { correlationId, replyTo: REPLY_QUEUE })
    } catch (error) { reject(error) }

});
```

but the problem was i have no idea how to return response of the request. my controller i tried to return queue response like this

```
@Post()
    public async postSurvey(survey: Survey): Promise<Survey> {
        var obj: Survey;
        await createClient().then((channel) => {
            sendRPCMessage(channel, survey, "survey_q_req").then((data) => {
                obj = data as Survey;
            }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
        }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
        return obj
    }
```

how to return response from the response queue of rabbitmq right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Post()
public async postSurvey(survey: Survey): Promise<Survey> {
    return createClient()
     .then(channel => {
        return sendRPCMessage(channel, survey, "survey_q_req")
     })
     .then(data => {
       return data;
     })
     .catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
}
```